# How can I make an array from curling a website?

Tags: arrays, unix

How can I make an array from a link?

I am trying to do it with:

```
IFS=$'\n'
array=($(curl http://www.site.com))
```

but I keep getting a syntax error

Comment: Please paste the error message you're getting. That's usually the most important clue to debug anything.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

> ```
> array=(($curl http://www.site.com))
>        ^^
> ```

Move the `$` slightly:

```
$ array=($(curl http://www.example.com))
         ^
$ echo ${array[3]}
    <title>Example Domain</title>
```

Comment: oh I actually had it like that, I just mistyped in my question. Do you know of anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: @boop This is the right way to do it. You might be printing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are using BASH arrays here. A common issue is that you're shebang is still pointing to the POSIX `sh`. The old POSIX `sh` doesn't support arrays. Make sure the top line of your file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```